# OAUTH API testing with Jmeter

Tags: oauth, jmeter

I need to test OAUTH 1.0 API testing with Jmeter.

Can anyone please guide me how to test OAUTH 1.0 API's testing with JMETER.

**We are passing 4 static keys Consumer Key, Consumer secret, Token and Token Secret**

Where do I need to pass these values?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pass **Consumer Key** and **Consumer Secret** to OAuth **Temporary Credentials Acquisition** endpoint, you will get **OAuth Token** and **Token Secret** as the response
2. Once done you need to pass the aforementioned **OAuth Token** and **Token Secret** to the **Authorization Endpoint**  - you will get the **Access Token**
3. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) as a child of the request and configure it like:

   ```
   Name: `Authorization`
   Value: `Bearer ${Access Token from Step 2}`
   ```

You might also need to sign the requests by encrypting the message with one of the following mechanisms:

- [HMAC-SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)
- [RSA-SHA1](https://www.w3.org/PICS/DSig/RSA-SHA1_1_0.html)

or if you are lucky your server will accept plain text requests (unlikely)

References:

- [OAuth Authorization Flow](https://oauth1.wp-api.org/docs/basics/Auth-Flow.html)
- [OAuth Core 1.0](https://oauth.net/core/1.0/)
- [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)